# Graphql query with contextdata throws validation error 'STRING' is not a valid 'ClaimValueType' @ 'page'

Tags: graphql, dxd-11.1, pca

I am trying to do graphql client call using postman, but i am getting Validation error

```
Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'contextData.type' 
with value 'StringValue{value='STRING'}' is not a valid 'ClaimValueType' @ 'page'
```

we are using **DXD 11.1**, could someone please help/advise me **what could be possible problem here**

my grapql query is

```
{
    page(pageId: 31319, namespaceId: 2, publicationId: 84323, 
    contextData: {
        uri:"taf:ish:userconditions",
        type:"STRING",
        value:"{\"PRODUCTID\":\"P199999}"}) {
        itemId        

            rawContent(renderContent: true) {
                data 
            }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the error and [this example in the documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-A9B11290-40A0-46A4-A997-0F77DDB5D719), the argument `contextData.type` probably isn't a valid `ClaimValueType`.

Perhaps you meant `type: STRING` instead of  `type:"STRING"`?

Comment: Thanks @Alvin, it worked for me.